# Trouble using _find query with use_index

Tags: couchdb

I am trying to use the MongoDB-like `_find` query in CouchDB 2.x:
http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/database/find.html

With the following, I get a warning that I should be using an index.

```
curl -k -X POST "$COUCHDB_HOST/vacation-at-ibm/_find" \
>      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>      -w "\nhttp_code=%{http_code}\n" \
>      --data-binary '
> {
>     "selector": {
>         "ownerId": {"$eq": "1A4061897"}
>     }
> }
> '

{"warning":"no matching index found, create an index to optimize query time",

"docs":[
{...}
http_code=200
```

But when I add the `use_index` option, I get an error that it can't find my index:

```
curl -k -X POST "$COUCHDB_HOST/vacation-at-ibm/_find" \
>      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>      -w "\nhttp_code=%{http_code}\n" \
>      --data-binary '
> {
>     "use_index": [
>         "_design/EventDocument",
>         "events-by-ownerId"
>     ],
>     "selector": {
>         "ownerId": {"$eq": "1A4061897"}
>     }
> }
> '
{"error":"unknown_error","reason":"Unknown Error: mango_idx :: {no_usable_index,no_index_matching_name}"}
```

I'm making the assumption that I should be specifying the design document key, and the view name. But that's a guess, because I have found absolutely no useful documentation for the `use_index` option. There are no examples of actually trying to use it. Here's my design document:

```
{
  "_id": "_design/EventDocument",
  "_rev": "1-115570169dec7d32845c3b7c6e6978fe",
  "language": "javascript",
  "views": {
    "events-by-ownerId": {
      "map": "function(doc) { if (doc.docType == 'event' && doc.ownerId) { var firstDate = null;  if (doc.date) { firstDate = doc.date;  }  emit([doc.ownerId, firstDate], doc); }}"
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know how to use this option? Am I using the wrong values for the design doc and the index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So when they say, **"Create an index"**, they refer to the [`/db/_index`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/database/find.html#post--db-_index) endpoint.

You need to create an index through this process. You can specify where you want to store the index, otherwise, CouchDB will create a design document and store the index in there.

Answer (score 2):

I was also confused by this feature. To use indexes in `_find` you have to create a Mango language index through the `_index` endpoint. The `use_index` field has to equal the name of the design document that contains the created index, and does not need the leading `_design/`; the design document's name will be a uuid if you did not specify `ddoc` when creating the index. If the design document `some-indexes` has more than one index, you can refer to it as `"use_index": "some-indexes/name"`. You can't refer to an index by its name alone without the design document name. Even if you specify `use_index`, the index will not be used unless your query includes all of the `fields` in the index definition.